# Editing a collection in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I was having problems updating child collections of my object ( [Foreign key constraint, EF with collection of childobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170101/foreign-key-constraint-ef-with-collection-of-childobjects/) ) which was solved using this guide: http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Binding-Model-Graphs-with-ASPNETMVC.aspx

When cleaning up my code, I moved the collection editing to a partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("_AttendeeInformationFields", Model.CaptureAttendeeInformationFields)
```

The partial view looks like this

```
@model ICollection<EventModel.Models.AttendeeInformationField>
<table id="CaptureAttendeeInformationFields">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.GetDisplayName(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.GetDisplayName(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Required)</th>
        <th>@Html.GetDisplayName(model => model.FirstOrDefault().FieldType)</th>
        @*<th>@Html.GetDisplayName(model => model.FirstOrDefault().InputType)</th>*@
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
@Html.LinkToAddNestedForm("Lägg till", "#CaptureAttendeeInformationFields", ".AttendeeInformationField", "CaptureAttendeeInformationFields", typeof(EventModel.Models.AttendeeInformationField))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
```

Then I have a EditorTemplate for AttendeeInformationField that looks like this

```
@model EventModel.Models.AttendeeInformationField
<tr class="AttendeeInformationField">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CaptureAttendeeInformationFields"))
{
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MagnetEventId) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Required)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FieldType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(EventModel.Models.FieldType)), Model.FieldType))</td>
    @*<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InputType)</td>*@
}
</tr>
```

The BeginCollectionItem is from this guide: http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/
This helps me with two things
1. The index is no longer a sequential 0-based integer series, and I can reorder my items, as well as add/delete without worrying about breaking the sequence.
2. The partial seems to loose the context, and my controls get names like "[0].Required" where it should be "CaptureAttendeeInformationField[0].Required". The BeginCollectionItem takes care of this.

The current problem is that these fixes doesn't seem to be compatible. I suppose it might have something to do with this disclaimer in the first article:

> within this implementation we assume that the index is an integer starting at 0

I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.
Adding items in this solution works.

**Ugly solution**
I sure hope this is not the only way to do this, but for now I've solved the problem like this:

```
foreach (var attendeeInformationField in viewModel.AttendeeInformationFields)
        {
            var attendeeInformationFieldId = attendeeInformationField.Id;
            var originalAttendeeInformationField = original.CaptureAttendeeInformationFields.FirstOrDefault(aif => aif.Id == attendeeInformationFieldId);
            if (originalAttendeeInformationField==null)
            {
                original.CaptureAttendeeInformationFields.Add(attendeeInformationField);
            }
            else
            {
                if (originalAttendeeInformationField != attendeeInformationField)
                {
                    originalAttendeeInformationField = attendeeInformationField;
                    originalAttendeeInformationField.FieldType = attendeeInformationField.FieldType;
                    //originalAttendeeInformationField.InputType = attendeeInformationField.InputType;
                    originalAttendeeInformationField.Name = attendeeInformationField.Name;
                    originalAttendeeInformationField.Required = attendeeInformationField.Required;
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't like it at all, but it works. There must be a better way of doing this.